# Cannot access the file: Permission denied - Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, software-installation, administrator

I have downloaded Virtualbox in order to run Android in it I have set up everything and tried to start it but unfortunately 2 errors have came up.

1. Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Android.
   The virtual machine 'Android' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1

   Details:

   ```
   Result Code: 
   NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
   Component: 
   Machine
   Interface: 
   IMachine {480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048}
   ```
2. Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

   The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with `/dev/vboxdrv`. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing

   ```
   /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
   ```

   as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install the DKMS package first. This package keeps track of Linux kernel changes and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.

   So it typed in the `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` into the terminal and that's what came up:

   ```
   /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
   Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
   Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules
   /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: 334: 
   /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: cannot create /var/log/vbox-install.log: Permission denied
    ...failed!
     (Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong)
   ```

   After that as it was saying in the terminal I typed in `/var/log/vbox-install.log` to check out what went wrong.

   ```
   /var/log/vbox-install.log
   bash: /var/log/vbox-install.log: Permission denied
   ```

   As the permission is denied I have typed in 'su sudo' to be as root:

   ```
   su sudo /var/log/vbox-install.log
   No passwd entry for user 'sudo'
   ```

   So I tried:

   ```
   su /var/log/vbox-install.log
   No passwd entry for user '/var/log/vbox-install.log'
   ```

   And then:

   ```
   sudo /var/log/vbox-install.log
   [sudo] password for mroovka: 
   sudo: /var/log/vbox-install.log: command not found
   ```

   So I just typed in 'su' then tried to check the `/var/log/vbox-install.log` again but the outcome was...

   ```
   mroovka@mroovka-N102SP-N100SP-N101SP:~$ su
   Password: 
   root@mroovka-N102SP-N100SP-N101SP:/home/mroovka# /var/log/vbox-install.log
   bash: /var/log/vbox-install.log: Permission denied
   ```

So I don't really know what to do, as I have only one account and I am the administrator.

Thank you in advance for your help.

PS. I know this question may be duplicate but I read a lot about it and it is very challenging for me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no /var/log/vbox-install.log, it was not created. The error when you tried to install the kernel module states that it couldn't create that file because it lacked permissions.

Please to run a program as root use sudo, in your case you need to type:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

If there is any problem with it you can read the log with the command:

```
gedit /var/log/vbox-install.log
```

No need to be root just to read it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. In the document this has shown 8 times in the file:
'/usr/share/virtualbox/src/vboxhost/build_in_tmp: 62: /usr/share/virtualbox/src/vboxhost/build_in_tmp: make: not found'...
what should I do now?

Comment: should i just install vbox via terminal

Comment: i typed this in:  sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic
the virtualbox works fine now thank you for helping me you are the best!

Answer (score 0):

su is a command to change the user completely and you should use it like this:

`su USERNAME`

but sudo is a command to have root privilages just in time and you can use it in this way:

`sudo COMMAND` ,then it will ask your password that you should enter.

Comment: That's what I have done already and the outcome was:
sudo: /var/log/vbox-install.log: command not found

Comment: read it again. your mistake.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Guys everything was fine until I actually installed the android on VB and it tried to run but it went for ages so i powered it off and that was the error: 
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Android.

Failed to get a console object from the direct session (VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE).

Result Code: VBOX_E_VM_ERROR (0x80BB0003)
Component: Machine
Interface: IMachine {480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048}

Also when I start he Android again it tells me to install it again in VB even though it has been already installed... may this be the file problem?

May anyone tell what is the issue and how to resolve this problem? thank you